# What is the difference between openCV and cv2?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am new to the openCV library. When I was first trying the code for a feature matching tutorial

[Python Tutorial Link](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html)

All other functions except for the 'drawMatches' function does not work. I figured out that my openCV version is not correct. Then I update my openCV version to the newest version(3.2.0) using command

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv' and 'conda update --all
```

The problem now is that all other functions does not work because it does not recognize cv2. The error I get is like the following:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/qdai/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so,

Library not loaded: @rpath/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.dylib 
Referenced from: /Users/qdai/anaconda/lib/libopencv_hdf.3.2.0.dylib
```

I don't know what is the relationship between cv2 and opencv. And how do I solve this problem?

Comment: This [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45518539/3904031) solved a similar/same problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the paths you have in your example, I am assuming you're on Mac?

If so, I had this same problem.

After having [homebrew installed](https://brew.sh) this ended up working for me:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv

cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py cv.py
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45518539/3904031) solved a similar/same problem for me.