# Library not loaded: @rpath/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.dylib

Tags: python, macos, opencv, anaconda, conda

How should I fix this?

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:02_02 mona$ python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:04:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mona/anaconda/lib/libopencv_hdf.3.2.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Installed opencv using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=3.2.0
```

and even tried:

```
$ conda install -c anaconda openblas=0.2.19
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /Users/mona/anaconda:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    libgfortran: 3.0.0-1       anaconda   
    openblas:    0.2.19-1      anaconda   

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

    conda:       4.3.22-py36_0 conda-forge --> 4.3.22-py36_0 anaconda
    conda-env:   2.6.0-0       conda-forge --> 2.6.0-0       anaconda

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

conda-env-2.6. 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00  90.59 kB/s
libgfortran-3. 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 387.65 kB/s
openblas-0.2.1 100% |################################| Time: 0:01:03 107.62 kB/s
conda-4.3.22-p 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 596.24 kB/s
```

But still the same error. 
Here's the output of my `conda list` https://pastebin.com/gP0F0Qnz
How should I fix it so that I can `import cv2`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mona

it seems that you do not have openblas installed, which is a required module of opencv, but somehow is not included in its dependencies so you have to install it manually, you may confirm this with `conda list|grep openblas`

If you do not have openblas, install it using following command:
`conda install -c conda-forge openblas=0.2.19`

Hope that helps

Comment: This just worked for me to, thanks! I wish I could accept your answer :-)